# Can you mix "would" with present-tense verbs?

Tags: grammar

Is the following sentence acceptable?

> I would be excited to see what my father looks like and what kind of a
>   person he is, but I would also be nervous about what he would think of me.

If not, would it have to be rewritten as so?

> I would be excited to see what my father looked like and what kind of
>   a person he was, but I would also be nervous about what he would think of
>   me.

Comment: Yes, the version with present tenses is acceptable. *Would* is in "past-tense" form, but it has non-past reference and signifies a present hypotheticality or future contingency. This use of the past form is very common with all the English modals.

Answer (score 1):

> I would be excited to see what my father looks like and what kind of a person he is, but I would also be nervous about what he would think of me.

Yes,this form is acceptable.  When built this way, it implies that *if you have the chance* to meet your father, you would be excited to know what he is like and what he thinks of you.

> I would be excited to see what my father looked like and what kind of a person he was, but I would also be nervous about what he would think of me.

This one is grammatically correct, but the implied meaning here is that your father is dead, or possibly it is unknown whether he is dead or not.

Another, different, way to phrase it, would be

> I am excited to see what my father looks like and what kind of a person he is, but am also be nervous about what he would think of me.

When phrased this way, the meaning is that *you are going* to meet your father.
To clarify, the difference between the two options you gave and the additional one I provided

1. You would like to meet your father, and might be able to.
2. You would like to meet your father, but he is gone.
3. You are meeting your father in the future.